# Swift save PHP session to stay authenticated

Tags: php, ios, swift

I am building an app, which has login page connected with my AWS server using PHP and MySQL, everything is working fine except that I have no idea how to save the PHP session within the app so the user can stay authenticated.

Part of my PHP code:

```
<?php
$session_start();
...
...
if($verify){
    echo "Verfied";
    $_SESSION["Authenticated"] = 1;
  } else {
    echo "Unverified";
    $_SESSION["Authenticated"] = 0;
  }
...
...
?>
```

Part of Swift code:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/login.php")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
        return
    }

    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
    }

    let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        if (responseString == "Vaild!") {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MainPageSegue", sender: self)
        } else {
            self.errorLabel.text = "Invalid username or password."
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

How can I save the session within my app so the user stay authenticated?

Comment: Why don't you use JWT Token? If you are using Mobile -> Backend is the best and secure way.

Comment: @UlyssesMarx JWT is not really secure: https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/03/jwt-json-web-tokens-is-bad-standard-that-everyone-should-avoid

Comment: Most secure thant php_sessions yes, and for example is not an standard, second that depends on how you implement the Tokenizer you cand build your own Token signed on PCI Complience your app is secure on the level you know how to do it. Good luck